# How to select with multiple subqueries?

Tags: sql

I don't know how else to call this.
I have this table right here:

[image: phpMyAdmin screenshot]

And as you can see `Titon` followed `SLH_444` and `Knoedel_475`.
Now, how can I select all rows for users whom `Titon` followed?

I expect a result of all rows where the `username` is either `SLH_444` or `Knoedel_475`

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4a986/1

This is what I have so far, but it errors because the subquery returns more than 1 row

```
SELECT * FROM ACTIVITIES 
WHERE targetname = 
(select targetname from ACTIVITIES 
where activity='followed' and username='Titon');
```

Comment: I reworded your question to ask what I believe you actually meant to ask.  Judging by the answer you selected, I think the rewording is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT * FROM ACTIVITIES 
WHERE username in 
(select targetname from ACTIVITIES 
where activity='followed' and username='Titon');
```

Although Titon has not followed `SLH_444`, he has followed `SLB_444`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT targetname FROM ACTIVITIES WHERE username = 'Titon' AND activity = 'followed';
```

Comment: This only returns 50% of the result I need. I updated my question with an SQL-Script I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename where activity='followed' and username='Titon'
```

Comment: This returns an empty result

Comment: that means nobody is following Titon :) try to see who is following knoedel_475 and check the result

Comment: Yes but it should work the other way. I want a query to show me all users Titon is following.